# jquery replace span text without destroying inner div

Tags: jquery, innerhtml, html

I have an issue where I need to replace the text in a span with other text, whilst at the same time not destroying a nested div.

Basically when I use the `.html()` method the inner div gets overwritten causing it to disappear.

Code below and also at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/wzZSx/)

```
    .textLabel {

        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: 200;
        letter-spacing:1px;
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
        height: 33px;
        line-height: 32px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 1);
        -moz-border-radius: 17px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 17px;
        border-radius: 17px;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 44px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    .circ 
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -10px;
            left: 7px;
        width: 13px;
        height: 13px;
        background-color: white;
        -moz-border-radius: 11px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
        border-radius: 11px;
        border: solid 4px black;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    .circ:hover 
    {
        position: absolute;
        /*top: 50%;*/
        margin-top:-20px;
        margin-left:-13px;

        width: 31px;
        height: 31px;
        background-color: blue;
        -moz-border-radius: 22px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 22px;
        border-radius: 22px;
        border: solid 6px white;
    }

    var otherText = "This is some other text";
            var noText = "";
            var spanID = "#s1";

            $("#b1").hover(function() {

              $(spanID).html(otherText);

            }, function() {

              $(spanID).html(noText);

            });
```

In this example when I hover over the div with id "b1" it disappears from the document.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A `div` (block element) cannot be inside a `span` (inline element). at least it is not valid. You should fix that.

Comment: Place your actual text within a `<span>` and use `$(spanID + ' span').text('text new');` .  That's much more efficient than trying to only replace part of the content.

Comment: N Rohler is correct. Might I suggest you turn that into an answer?

Comment: @Felix Kling is the alternative to create a container `div` for both the `span` and the `div`? I need to position the 'dot' as if it was inside the `span`.

Comment: You could just use another `span` instead of `div`. You can use `display: block` to render it like a block element.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, would be to just place the text in a span and then using `text`, or `html`.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzZSx/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could detach the span, replace the HTML and then reattach the span like this:

```
$("#b1").hover(function(){
    var store = $('#b1', spanID).detach();
    $(spanID).html(otherText);
    $(spanID).append(store);

}, function() {
    var store = $('#b1', spanID).detach();
    $(spanID).html(noText);
    $(spanID).append(store);
});
```

Forked Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wzZSx/1/

I hope this helps!